# How to serialize collection of classes that uses variables of reference type?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I have abstract Skill class which provides Command pattern and its children . I need to serialize collection of Skill instances and then deserialize and set references to some instances of other classes.
How do I do this correctly?

I can't think of a solution other than creating skill mappers (one for each child type) and then creating the where mapper is argument constructor. But in this case I can't deserialize collection in generic manner.

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class Skill : ICommand
{
  [field: NonSerialized] public SkillItemInfo Info { get; private set; } // Unity.ScriptableObject
  [field: NonSerialized] public List<ISkill> SkillBlockers { get; private set; }// Another skills that restrict to use current

  public Skill(SkillItemInfo itemInfo, IEnumerable<ISkill> blocker){/*concrete realisation*/}
  public abstract void Apply();
  public abstract void Undo();
}
```

```
[Serializable]
public class SkillA: Skill
{
    [NonSerialized]ReferenceTypeA variable;
    // ... other fields
    public SkillA(ReferenceTypeA variable, SkillItemInfo itemInfo, IEnumerable<ISkill> blocker)
    :base(itemInfo, blocker) {/*concrete realisation*/}

    //... Some methods
}

[Serializable]
public class SkillB: Skill
{
    [NonSerialized]ReferenceTypeB variable;
    // ... other fields
    public SkillB(ReferenceTypeB variable, SkillItemInfo itemInfo, IEnumerable<ISkill> blocker)
    :base(itemInfo, blocker) {/*concrete realisation*/}

     //... Some methods
}
```

```
[Serializable]
public class SkillCollection
{
    List<Skill> collection = new List<Skill>();
    public IEnumerable<ICommand> Commands => collection;

    public void Add(IEnumerable<Skill> skill){/*concrete realisation*/}
    public void Clear(){/*concrete realisation*/}

}
```

Comment: The fields in your skill classes are all `[NonSerialized]` .. so what are you going to Serialize then?

Comment: I'm not going to serialize this fields. That's why they are marked as [NonSerialized]. Because they're reference types. And I need update this classes from another classes on every load. ItemInfo, for example, as I mentioned is a scriptable object. I'm not going to serialize it.